# Why is it sufficient to prove for $H^0$

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology

I am reading the corestriction homomorphism on cohomology. To prove a proposition (for example the composition of corestriction and restrcition is the multiplication by the index), it says that it is sufficient to prove it for zeroth cohomology group $H^0$. I do not understand which result it is using. I will be thankful to you if you could explain me the concept.

Comment: Look for results/techniques labelled "dimension shifting". They usually work by saying, for every module $M$ every integer $n$, there is some module $X$ so that $H^0(X) = H^n(M)$.